# Is a validation the proper way to see if a div is empty?

Tags: jquery, html

url: http://adamginther.com

I am trying to validate a div when the image "DragonUp" is pressed and check if that value is empty. If it is empty then it will append that div with a paragraph and image, if it does have text in it then it will empty that div. This is not working, is validation the proper way to doing this?

```
<div id="description"></div>
<p id="checkOut">
You should check out some of my work
</p>
</div>
<section id="portfoliopics">
<p>Information Architecture</p>
<img src="images/dragonup.png" id="dragonup" alt="DragonUp">
<img src="images/province.jpg" id="provincesports" alt="The Province Sports">
<img src="images/ayogo.jpg" id="ayogo" alt="ayogo">
<p>Design</p>
<img src="images/rebellious.png" alt="Rebellious by Nav" id="rebellious">
<img src="images/attack.png" alt="Attack of the Space Leprechauns">
<p>Development</p>
<img src="images/form.png" alt="Form Design" id="formdesign">
<img src="images/imageswap.png" alt="Image Swap">
<img src="images/popup.png" alt="Pop-up Window">
<img src="images/learningios.png" alt="Learning iOS Development" id="learningios">
<p>More Stuff</p>
<img src="images/canucks.jpg" alt="canucks">
<img src="images/saveinte.png" alt="Save Interactive Design">
</section>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#dragonup").click(function() {
        $('#description').val();
        if ('#description' === '') {
        $('#description').empty();
        $("#description").prepend('<p><class id="blueText">You are viewing: DragonUp Wireframes </class><br> Role: User Experience Design<br><br>DragonUp is a game created by East Side Games for iOS and it is currently being ported over to Facebook. It is a game that draws inspiration from Dragonvale and Tiny Tower and has players building up a collection of dragons. Kotaku describes it as A dragon vomit harvesting game, and that makes all the difference.<br><br>I was tasked with proposing a re-design of its UI. Currently, the game has 10 different options in the menu. With this in mind, my goal was to create a more streamlined menu for new users and more fluid navigation for experienced players. I was able to achieve this and accomplished having four different options in the menu while still containing the same functionality and increasing usability.</p>');
                $("#description").append('<img src="images/work/dragonup-wireframe1.png">');
                $("#beforeClick").remove();
                $('#checkOut').empty();
                $('#checkOut').append('You should also check out:');
            }
            else {
                $('#description').empty();
            }
    })
})
```

Comment: Thank you. I have made this change. It will still not append.

Comment: funny and good looking portfolio! ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are testing against the wrong thing - your code `if ('#description' === '')` will never validate, you need to change this to `if ($('#description').text() === '')`

Answer (score 0):

it should be:

```
$('#description').html();
```

`.val()` is for inputs

Answer (score 0):

```
if ('#description' === '') { ... }
```

This compares two literal strings which are obviously not equal to each other, thus always giving a `false` result. You'll need to retrieve the `#description` element and retrieve some information about it.

There are quite a few ways you could go about this:

- `if ($('#description').html() === '') { ... }`
  This will match if the HTML content of the `#description` element is empty. Text nodes and comments are retained.
- `if ($('#description').text() === '') { ... }`
  This will match if the text content of the `#description` element is empty. (The text content is its "flat" content, e.g. the HTML tags are stripped off.) Comments are discarded.
- `if ($('#description').children().length === 0) { ... }`
  This will match if the `#description` element has no child elements. Text nodes and comments are not considered, i.e. `<div id="description">Foo <!-- Bar --></div>` has no child nodes according to this method.

If you know you only need to worry about actual child nodes (e.g. an `<img>` tag), `.children().length` is probably the easiest choice. Otherwise, you'll have to look at the actual text contents and possibly `.trim()` it before checking if its *truly* empty:

```
if ($('#description').text().trim() === '') { ... }
```

or equivalently:

```
if ($('#description').text().trim().length === 0) { ... }
```